# Installshield msi unable to register flash.ocx

Tags: crystal-reports, installshield

I am creating an msi installer using an Installshield setup project. The application is currently working correctly and is in use as a Click-Once application, but there is now a business requirement to create installation package (i.e. an msi installer).

Installer "works fine on my machine", but on a user setup it throws:

```
Error 1904. Module [path]\flash.ocx failed to register.
HRESULT -2147220473
```

I have confirmed that flash.ocx is being copied to the program directory.

The file appears to be a dependency of Crystal Reports, which is embedded in the application.

### Edit

`flash.ocx`, I've found out, is specifically a dependent of `CrystalDesisions.Windows.Forms`. It is used in the `CrystalReportViewer` control.

Answer (score 0):

I googled for just that string and [this](https://support.solarwinds.com/Success_Center/Log_Event_Manager_(LEM)/Error_1904...failed_to_register_error_message_during_Crystal_Reports_Runtime_installation) was the 2nd response. Have you tried this?

Comment: This appears to be related to a .dll and occurs when installing the runtime. My issue is a ocx and is when using an InstallShield install of a desktop application using Crystal embedded.