# C# Crystal Reports Error occurd when created application setup using installShieldProject

Tags: c#, crystal-reports, installshield

I have created win-form application using Visual studio 2015.I have made its setup using installShield project.My application have some features related with crystal report.After creating the setup file when try to install that application another computer 2 errors have occurd when install it and after installation run the programme.

when install the application to another computer
[image]

After installation when run it

[image]

How to fix it?

Comment: Hmm, I think this one has been seen [before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48946491/installshield-msi-unable-to-register-flash-ocx).

Answer (score 2):

I have found out what are the reasons to cause those errors.

Solution is when we creating our setup using  **InstallShieldProject**,In ApplicationFiles(3rd step) After you have add  PrimaryOutput Right click on PrimaryOutput and select Properties.

After a window pop up.

[image]

- then choose Properties and select ".NET-Settings". Then select "Scan at build:" and Choose "Properties only"

select **COM & .NET-Settings**.

then you can see in .NET Properties Scan at Build already selected Dependencies and Properties.In there you must select Properties only

[image]

after Apply then Ok. This is the change for when your application  use **Crystal report** related some features and you creating setup uisng **installShield**

[image]

try this..