# WPF application setup project error - Flash.ocx failed to register

Tags: wpf, windows-installer, installshield

We have made a WPF application and added setup project using InstallShield Limited Edition 2015 in normal mode (not in `Run As Administrator`). it gives below wrror.

[image]

Now we tried to manually copying this file in creating installation process and run project in `Run As Administrator` mode, the `setup.exe` crashes.

Please help.

Comment: This was answered on an earlier [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48946491/installshield-msi-unable-to-register-flash-ocx/48963878#48963878).

Answer (score 0):

Some tasks require admin privileges.  EG installing new fonts.
If your users don't have admin privileges then you need to either avoid "installing" a component and instead just deliver it to disk OR some sort of work round.
Registration of an ocx results in writing to the users registry.
One thing you could do is just deliver that ocx to disk ( not install, as such ), then add the entries to the user branch of their registry.
Offhand, I don't know whether installshield allows you to do scripted tasks.
If it doesn't, you could write that registry entry when your app runs. Check if it's not there and add.